# Passing objectId via prepareForSegue using Parse PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform

This is very likely a simple answer.  I am using PFQueryTableViewController to populate a table view.  I want to pass the Parse objectId of the current row to my crDetailViewController but can't figure out how.  The variable I'm trying to pass is called critterId.

I've updated my code to reflect Race B's @race-b suggestion below and it enables the build to succeed but I get a breakpoint error when I select an actual cell it creates a breakpoint.  When I look at the debug code it shows a value of nil for the object, so it's not getting passed somehow since by definition there's an entity selected, otherwise how would the cell be selectable in the first place?  Thanks for help!

import UIKit

class crTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

```
// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "CritterType"
    self.textKey = "Name"
    self.imageKey = "mainPhoto"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false

}


// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "CritterType")
     return query
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("crDetailSegue", sender: self)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "crDetailSegue" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                as! crDetailViewController

            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let row = myIndexPath!.row
               println(row)
            println(myIndexPath)
            detailViewController.critterId = self.objectAtIndexPath(myIndexPath)
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There should be an objectAtIndexPath that you can use that will return the object at whatever indexPath.row that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Parse puts the data into an array called `objects` so to pass the object instead of the ID use the following code:

```
detailViewController.critter = self.objects[indexPath.row]
```